# How to concatenate two or more big XML files in Java (not using memory)?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Our application needs to concatenate two or more XMLs files, one after another. The result should be another XML file. We can't store the XML into memory because these could be files of hundreds of MB.

The application is made in Java with spring and spring-batch, but any other library could be also welcome.

To clarify, this is my XML:

Sample file:

```xml
  <item>
    <name>x</name>
    <surname>y</surname>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Z</name>
    <surname>aa</‌​surname>
  </item>
  ...
```

We can have those items inside an `xml` root tag, but it could also be a list of nodes prepared by us, just to be able to concatenate one after each other without problems of validation. After concatenating all files, we can add a header and a footer.

If we make it like that, the problem could be reduced to concatenate two plain text files.

Comment: Concatenating XML files doesn't produce a valid XML file. Do you want to concatenate the children of the roots under the same root? Something else maybe?

Comment: Ignoring the <xml> first tag, the XMLs that I have could be concatenated without problems. Their structure is simple: <item><name>x</name><surname>y</surname></item><item><name>Z</name><surname>aa</surname></item>. They're XMLs but it could also be treated as plain txt if there's a better solution

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the output is a valid XML while keeping the memory usage low, use a [SAX parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) to process large XML files with low memory consumption.

Parse the first file and process all of it's contents (all elements the parser recognizes) to a output file, then perform the same with the second file. Depending on tyhe definition of your XMLs, merge contents of elements as needed (make sure there's a single top-level element at least).

Memory consumed by a SAX parser should be proportional to document depth (i.e. the number of nested XML elements), not the overall number of elements in the document.

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that in the answer. Just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template name="main">
  <output>
   <xsl:for-each select="'input1.xml', 'input2.xml'">
    <xsl:stream href="{.}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:stream>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </output>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should work in Saxon-EE, but it may not be the most cost-effective solution if you only need to run this once.

Answer (score 0):

Write the first XML file to disc then append the second file to it? The Apache Commons libraries are very useful.

Apache Commons FileUtils: [link here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/package-summary.html)

Apache Commons StringUtils: [link here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html)

Comment: This will not work, as a XML file must have only one root element, so some XML parsing is needed to concatenate two XML files into a valid third one.

Comment: As I posted in my edited question, it would be possible to avoid the root node, so we can put one "xml" after another without problems. The problem to me with that solution is that FileUtils would employ the memory to make the read-write... isn't it?